# Rails - rendering a search result in json to a form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-4

My class Contribution belongs_to User. I have a form for a new contribution which includes a search field for for the user to whom the contribution will belong -

in /contributions/new.html.erb -

```
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search], id: "search" %>
<%= link_to "Search", search_contributions_path, id: "search_submit" %>
```

in application.js.erb

```
$(document).on("click", "a#search_submit", function(){
   $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("href"),
      data: {query: $("#search").val() },
      success: function(data) {
        var user = $.parseJSON(json);
      }
   });
});
```

and in contribution_controller.rb -

```
def search
    @users = User.search(params[:search])
    render :users => @users.to_json
end
```

My controller is trying to render a page - how do I make it return the result I want to the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could write:

```
    render json: { users: @users.to_json }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure its my javascript which is wrong - adding your line above results a page being displayed with the hash {"users":"null"} - but this is an improvement. I'm going to close this and rephrase the q I think - but thanks for your help :)

Comment: @RADan give a look to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't a `respond_to` fix that? Something like

```
respond_to :html, :xml, :json
```

depending on the formats you want to "respond to", obviously.

Here's the source http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/ClassMethods/respond_to

Answer (score 0):

You must use the following in your controller:

```
respond_to :html, :xml, :json
```

And You can return json as the following:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: @users.result() }
end
```

Or as the following:

```
render json: { :users => @users.result().to_json }
```

I think you used ransak for searching, so you need use `@users.result().to_json` instead of `@users.to_json`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is not related to json, your issue is related to javascript change your ajax call to be:

```
$(document).on("click", "a#search_submit", function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.ajax({
      url: $(this).attr("href"),
      data: {query: $("#search").val() },
      success: function(data) {
        var user = $.parseJSON(json);
      }
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi A - I've made the change you suggested, but I'm still getting a routed to /contributions/search which just contains the following html - `<pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">{"users":"null"}</pre>` - it's really weird.